# What is the equivalent of a callback `req` parameter in Node-red?

Tags: express, node-red

I have developed a simple middleware in node-express that catches `PUT` requests.

In the `index.js` file  the actions to take for each request to be managed are specified. For example:

```
router.put("/:dev", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.dev);
  //do something
  res.status(200).json({status:"ok"});
});
```

Now I am interested to replicate this in `node-red`.
In `express` I extracted some information from the `req` parameter.

Is there any equivalent to `req` parameter in node-red from which I can extract the same information?

Comment: Have you tried routing a http-in to a debug node (set to whole message)?

Comment: Yes it prints only the body of the request.

Comment: Actually setting the Debug to `complete msg object` instead of `msg.payload` allows me to see the information I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the info sidebar of the http-in node:

Creates an HTTP end-point for creating web services.

> **Outputs**
>
> *payload* - For a GET request, contains an object of any query string
>   parameters. Otherwise, contains the body of the HTTP request.
>
> *req*  -   An HTTP request object. This object contains multiple properties that provide information about the request.
>
> - body - the body of the incoming request. The format will depend on the request.
> - headers - an object containing the HTTP request headers.
> - query - an object containing any query string parameters.
> - params - an object containing any route parameters.
> - cookies - an object containing the cookies for the request.
> - files - if enabled within the node, an object containing any files uploaded as part of a POST request.